# Handle submission from outside the form when using Formik

Tags: reactjs, formik

I have an ant design `modal` in which i have a `Formik` component. How can I handle `form` submission from outside the `form` ? I want to submit the `form` from the modal `save` button.

Answer (score 2):

When the `Formik` component is used, the render method receives a set of props. One of them is called [`submitForm`](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/blob/master/docs/api/formik.md#submitform---promise), you can call it to trigger a form submission outside of the `form`.

```js
const BasicExample = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>My Form</h1>
    <Formik
      initialValues={{name: "jared"}}
      onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
          actions.setSubmitting(false);
        }, 1000);
      }}
      render={props => (
        <div>
          <form>
            <input
              type="text"
              onChange={props.handleChange}
              onBlur={props.handleBlur}
              value={props.values.name}
              name="name"
            />
          </form>
          <button onClick={props.submitForm}>Submit from outside the form</button>
        </div>
      )}
    />
  </div>
);
```